# Cannot see files opened by a process

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, lsof

I know I can use lsof -p  or ls /proc//fd to lists the files open by a process.

However, my question is, lets suppose I have a bash script running which is accessing a certain file X.

When I run the bash script and do a lsof -p  or ls /proc//fd, I see the bash script name as one of the file open by the process.

Is there anyway to list file X here or by any other way that will tell me that file X is been accessed here ?

Comment: If you aren't seeing X in the list, you should note that clearly in your question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I wasnt sure if this is possible to do, thats why the question. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text-based adventure:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch input.txt
$ cat > test.sh <<EOF
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
> tail -f input.txt
> EOF
$ chmod u+x test.sh
$ ./test.sh &
[1] 921
$ ps --forest -g $(ps -o sid= -p $!) w
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  574 pts/4    Ss     0:00 bash
  921 pts/4    S      0:00  \_ bash ./test.sh
  927 pts/4    S      0:00  |   \_ tail -f input.txt
  984 pts/4    R+     0:00  \_ ps --forest -g 574 w
```

So you can see that when you run a script which contains a command which reads a file there are actually three processes involved: the interactive Bash session and its [descendants](https://superuser.com/a/822450/2259), the script, and the command in the script (plus the `ps` we just ran).

So if you want to know about files used by the script you either have to get to the files with at least one `ps` command. But if you instead just want to know **which program is accessing a *specific* file** you can ask `lsof` directly:

```
$ lsof input.txt 
COMMAND PID          USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
tail    927      username    3r   REG   0,45        0 2047211 input.txt
```

Comment: So no easy way programmatically :)